# Using python 3.6 to transform dirty data from and Access database

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access, data-cleaning

When I was about 19 or 20 my Dad typed some records of British Army Officers in World War 1 into a an Access 1.0 database. All was for the last 27 years or so until he suddenly remembered he had done this and decided that I should "put it on the internet" for him (I had been drinking so I immediately agreed).

The good news is it's a single table, the bad news is that the data typed in 1990 has not really stood the test of time. There is a lot of abbreviation and slightly different spellings of things which should be the same which will spoil the look of the document and make search difficult.

The CSV header looks like:

```
Soldier,SoldierName,Notes,Christian Name,Rank,Regiment,Appointment,Grade,Date Appointed
```

The data looks like:

```
2876,"Furber","Vice Capt G W R Stacpoole DSO Res of Off LG29113 2984 26/3/1915.   Replaced by Lt A H Gordon Ind Army Res of Off LG29555 4121 20/4/1916.","M","Capt","Re
```

See how the word "captain" is spelt "capt", it is also spelt "cptn", "cpt" and so on.

I'd like to process the file and correct these. Using python 3.6 I read in the csv and substitute any ranks in the dictionary keys with their corrected ranks:

```
correct_ranks = {
    'cap'                        : 'captain',
    'temp cap'                   : 'temporary captain',
    'temp capt'                  : 'temporary captain',
    'temp capt act maj'          : 'temporary captain acting major',
    'temp capt temp maj'         : 'temporary captain temporary major',
    'temp capt hon maj'          : 'temporary captain the honorable major',
    'temp capt hon'              : 'temporary captain the honorable',
    'capt brevet lt col'         :  'captain brevet lieutenant colonel',
    'capt earl of'               :  'captain earl of',
    'capt hon'                   :  'captain the honorable',
    'hon capt'                   :  'captain the honorable',
}
```

I've got to do a similar job for the regiments they belong to also where my earliest solution was to use a list of regexes:

```
s =  re.sub(r'\bdrgns\b', 'Dragoons', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\bdgn\b', 'Dragoon', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\bgds\b', 'Guards', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\binf\b', 'Infantry', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\bbde\b', 'Brigade', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\bhsld\b', 'Household', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\bres\b', 'Reserve', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\byeo\b', 'Yeomanry', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\bco of\b', 'County of', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\bco\b', 'County', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\blon(d?)\b', 'London', s)
```

I've got this working pretty ok but sometimes a string doesn't seem to get transformed at the end so my solution seems "naive". My question:

What are good ways of approaching a task like this (I can program a little in python and I've got most of the steps working like extracting from access mdb and publishing it back to a google sheet. Suggestions for strategies for cleanup and tidying are what would help.

Comment: "I had been drinking so I immediately agreed" -- oh dear. I'm not a python coder by any means, just wanted to sympathize.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know,
I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems." The database engine that you are using to read the database has the ability to create new tables and databases and update queries and append queries. It is a /fabulous/ environment for doing data cleaning. In contrast, CSV is, sadly, a really sad environment for doing that...

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have Microsoft Access running on Windows 3.1